# VMware vCenter Server Appliance VAMI (https://vCSA:5480) stuck on "Getting Started - vCenter Server" after upgrading from 6.7 -> 7.0

Tags: vmware-vcenter

This vCSA was recently upgraded from 6.7u3 to 7.0. The vCenter is 100% operational from a vSphere perspective. However, we cannot get into the VAMI (vCenter Appliance Manager Interface) at https://vCSA:5480

This is very bad because we cannot update, upgrade or backup the vCSA without access to the VAMI. To be clear, we can login but there is a blank white window in the center of the web-UI and this text is behind it:

> *"vCenter Server 7.0 has been successfully installed. However, additional steps must be completed before it is available for use.
>   Click one of the links below to continue setup. vCenter has been
>   restored. However, additional steps must be completed before it is
>   available for use. Click the link below to continue.*
>
> *This vCenter Server cannot be used or repaired because a failure was encountered. You need to deploy a new vCenter Server. **Failure
>   details**"* (cannot get to this link, so it cannot be clicked)

Here is a screenshot of the VAMI page;
[image]

Can this be fixed? If so, how?

Comment: I know you've sorted the problem already but out of interest did you roll back the update and retry? if so did you get the same issue? I beta-tested 7 but I'm waiting for a while to go for it in Production - it's very nice though isn't it :)

Comment: Hey Chopper3, VMware Support was quickly able to identify and fix the issue, we didn't have to roll-back the upgrade, no. And yes, I'm a big fan of vSphere 7!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this issue fixed with the steps in this KB:
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/67179

Comment: This answer was provided by VMware Support.

Answer (score 0):

After updating my vCSA I usually have to clear my browser's cache in order for the vCSA web pages to display properly.   Hopefully VMware fixes this in future updates.

Comment: Thanks, that's not the the issue here though. The URL always redirects to: `https://vcsa6-7.myDomain.local:5480/configure/#/installer?locale=en`

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty unfortunate and the statement that you need to deploy a new vCenter server is definitive.

If you have support with VMware, I would say to exercise it.  Else, your only other option is likely to redeploy.

Comment: Thanks, John. We will deploy a new vCSA and set it up in linked-mode, then decommission this faulty one, and/or work with VMware support to get this resolved. If I do find a resolution I will post back here.